# Metodo para trocar imagens JavaScript / html

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo fazer com meu site troque determinadas imagens, criei o seguinte código, alguém por ventura pode apontar erros..?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    function ImgsRandom(){

                    var trocar=new Array()

                    trocar[0]='<img src="site.projeto/Logo_pilates.jpg" alt=""/>';

                    trocar[1]='<img src="site.projeto/equipamento.jpg" alt=""/>';

                    trocar[2]='<img src="site.projeto/equipamento_02.jpg" alt=""/>';

                    var whichtrocar=Math.floor(Math.random()*(trocar.length));

                    document.getElementById("imgsrandon").innerHTML = trocar[whichquote];

                    }

                    window.onload=ImgsRandom;

                    </script>
```

Comment: O navegador já faz isso, basta olhar o console do mesmo que haverão as possíveis mensagens de erro.

Comment: Qual erro é reportado pelo navegador ?

Answer (score 0):

Bem, o erro que você tá tentando achar tá no `trocar[whichquote]` troque por `trocar[whichtrocar]`. E comece a analisar os erros pelo browser com `CTRL+SHIFT+I` e clique na aba `Console` lá aparecerá os erros!

Answer (score 0):

Ao acessar o valor da lista de imagens você está usando a variável  **whichquote** que até então não existe, só alterando para **whichtrocar** teoricamente já vai funcionar.

Segue um exemplo apenas com uma alteração, ao invés de criar uma tag img eu altero o atributo src de uma imagem existente.

```js
  function ImgsRandom()
  {
      // lista de imagens
      var trocar = [
      'http://www.drodd.com/images15/1-4.png',
      'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/j/9/x/c/z/blue-rounded-square-with-number-2-md.png',
      'http://ghzwireless.com/live/files/No3-big.png' ];

      // criando valor randômico
      var whichtrocar = Math.floor(Math.random() * (trocar.length));

      // alterando o atributo 'src' da imagem
      document.getElementById("imgsrandon").src = trocar[whichtrocar];
  }

  window.onload = ImgsRandom;
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <img id="imgsrandon" />
    
</body>
</html>
```